# How to use the "Any Signer" option vía the API

Tags: docusignapi

We want to use the "Any Signer" option using the REST API.
I found it described in 
https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/cdse-user-guide/Content/advanced-sending/send-to-any-signer.htm.
Unfortunatly I couldn't configure such a group for my account. Neither did I find any hint on this topic in the REST API.
We have a group of potential signers and two of them must sign the envelope.
Is there any way to realize it?

Answer (score 3):

The 'Any Signer' feature is deprecated and has a December 2016 target for being disabled. It has been replaced with a newer option called 'Signing Groups'. You can read up on this at https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/cdse-user-guide-signing-groups-overview, and then review how to use these via the API from our docs too: https://docs.docusign.com/search/?q=signing%20group